# How to make an object in VPython move through the camera automatically?

Tags: python, python-2.7, vpython

I have this grocery isle and I'm supposed to make it seem as if the person is walking through the isle, but in order to do that the object has to pass the camera and every time it gets close, it hits the frame of the window and it almost look like it backs off and goes in the opposite direction. But if I zoom in a little, then it goes through but slows down mid-way. Is there a way for the object to move through the camera automatically? Thanks

```
from visual import *

sphere(pos=(0,0,0), radius = 0.5)
text(pos=(-2,1,0), text="Center")

rightside = box(pos=(10,0,-40), axis=(1,300,0), height=0.5, width=60, length=12, material=materials.emissive)
leftside = box(pos=(-10,0,-40), axis=(-1,300,0), height=0.5, width=60, length=12, material=materials.emissive)
bottomside = box(pos=(0,-5.8,-40), axis=(1,0,0), height=0.5, width=60, length=20, color=color.cyan, material=materials.emissive)

leftfirstshelf = box(pos=(8,0,-40), axis=(1,0,0), height=0.5, width=60, length=4, color=color.cyan, material=materials.emissive)
leftsecondshelf = box(pos=(-8,0,-40), axis=(1,0,0), height=0.5, width=60, length=4, color=color.white, material=materials.emissive)
leftthirdshelf = box(pos=(-8,-4,-40), axis=(1,0,0), height=0.5, width=60, length=4, color=color.cyan, material=materials.emissive)


rightfirstshelf = box(pos=(8,4,-40), axis=(1,0,0), height=0.5, width=60, length=4, color=color.white, material=materials.emissive)
rightsecondshelf = box(pos=(-8,4,-40), axis=(1,0,0), height=0.5, width=60, length=4, color=color.cyan, material=materials.emissive)
rightthirdshelf = box(pos=(8,-4,-40), axis=(1,0,0), height=0.5, width=60, length=4, color=color.white, material=materials.emissive)


cheeriosbox = box(pos=(8,6,-60), axis=(1,0,0), height=4, width=2.5, length=0.8, color=color.yellow, material=materials.emissive)
cheeriostext = text(pos=(7.7,7,-61), axis=(0,0,25), height=0.5, width=2.5, length=0.8, color=color.black, text='Cheerios')


watermelon = ellipsoid(pos=(8,2,-40), height=3, width=3.5, length=3, color=color.green, material=materials.emissive)


cokecan = cylinder(pos=(-8,-3.5,-60), height=0, width=0, length=3, color=color.red, material=materials.emissive, axis=(0,7,0))
cokecantext = text(pos=(-7.1,-2,-59), height=1, width=2, length=1, axis=(0,0,-25), color=color.black, text="Coke")


leftcarrotbody = cone(pos=(-8,0.5,-30), radius=0.2, color=color.orange, axis=(0,0,3), material=materials.emissive)
leftcarrottop = sphere(pos=(-8,0.5,-30),radius=0.3, color=color.green, material=materials.emissive)

middlecarrotbody = cone(pos=(-7.5,0.5,-30), radius=0.2, color=color.orange, axis=(0,0,3), material=materials.emissive)
middlecarrottop = sphere(pos=(-7.5,0.5,-30),radius=0.3, color=color.green, material=materials.emissive)

rightcarrotbody = cone(pos=(-7,0.5,-30), radius=0.2, color=color.orange, axis=(0,0,3), material=materials.emissive)
rightcarrottop = sphere(pos=(-7,0.5,-30),radius=0.3, color=color.green, material=materials.emissive)


orangefruit = sphere(pos=(-7.5,5.3,-15), radius=1, color=color.orange, material=materials.emissive)


bottomrowcupone = cylinder(pos=(8,-3.75,-15), radius=0.5, height=2, axis=(0,0.9,0),color=color.blue, material=materials.emissive)
bottomrowcuptwo = cylinder(pos=(8,-3.75,-14), radius=0.5, height=2, axis=(0,0.9,0),color=color.blue, material=materials.emissive)
bottomrowcupthree = cylinder(pos=(8,-3.75,-13), radius=0.5, height=2, axis=(0,0.9,0),color=color.blue, material=materials.emissive)
bottomrowcupfour = cylinder(pos=(8,-3.75,-12), radius=0.5, height=2, axis=(0,0.9,0),color=color.blue, material=materials.emissive)

thirdrowcupone = cylinder(pos=(8,-2.86,-14.5), radius=0.5, height=2, axis=(0,0.9,0),color=color.blue, material=materials.emissive)
thirdrowcuptwo = cylinder(pos=(8,-2.86,-13.5), radius=0.5, height=2, axis=(0,0.9,0),color=color.blue, material=materials.emissive)
thirdrowcupthree = cylinder(pos=(8,-2.86,-12.5), radius=0.5, height=2, axis=(0,0.9,0),color=color.blue, material=materials.emissive)

secondrowcupone = cylinder(pos=(8,-1.97,-14), radius=0.5, height=2, axis=(0,0.9,0),color=color.blue, material=materials.emissive)
secondrowcuptwo = cylinder(pos=(8,-1.97,-13), radius=0.5, height=2, axis=(0,0.9,0),color=color.blue, material=materials.emissive)

topcup = cylinder(pos=(8,-1.08,-13.5), radius=0.5, height=2, axis=(0,0.9,0),color=color.blue, material=materials.emissive)


a = vector(10,0,-40)
b = vector(-10,0,-40)
c = vector(0,-5.8,-40)
d = vector(8,0,-40)
e = vector(-8,0,-40)
f = vector(-8,-4,-40)
g = vector(8,4,-40)
h = vector(-8,4,-40)
i = vector(8,-4,-40)
j = vector(8,6,-60)
k = vector(7.7,7,-61.15)
l = vector(8,2,-40)
m = vector(-8,-3.5,-60)
n = vector(-7.1,-2,-59)
o = vector(-8,0.5,-30)
p = vector(-8,0.5,-30)
q = vector(-7.5,0.5,-30)
r = vector(-7.5,0.5,-30)
s = vector(-7,0.5,-30)
t = vector(-7,0.5,-30)
u = vector(-7.5,5.3,-15)
v = vector(8,-3.75,-15)
w = vector(8,-3.75,-14)
x = vector(8,-3.75,-13)
y = vector(8,-3.75,-12)
z = vector(8,-2.86,-14.5)
aia = vector(8,-2.86,-13.5)
bib = vector(8,-2.86,-12.5)
cic = vector(8,-1.97,-14)
did = vector(8,-1.97,-13)
eie = vector(8,-1.08,-13.5)


while a.z < 100:

    rate(20)

    rightside.pos = a

    leftside.pos = b

    bottomside.pos = c

    leftfirstshelf.pos = d

    leftsecondshelf.pos = e

    leftthirdshelf.pos = f

    rightfirstshelf.pos = g

    rightsecondshelf.pos = h

    rightthirdshelf.pos = i

    cheeriosbox.pos = j

    cheeriostext.pos = k

    watermelon.pos = l

    cokecan.pos = m

    cokecantext.pos = n

    leftcarrotbody.pos = o

    leftcarrottop.pos = p

    middlecarrotbody.pos = q

    middlecarrottop.pos = r

    rightcarrotbody.pos = s

    rightcarrottop.pos = t

    orangefruit.pos = u

    bottomrowcupone.pos = v

    bottomrowcuptwo.pos = w

    bottomrowcupthree.pos = x

    bottomrowcupfour.pos = y

    thirdrowcupone.pos = z

    thirdrowcuptwo.pos = aia

    thirdrowcupthree.pos = bib

    secondrowcupone.pos = cic

    secondrowcuptwo.pos = did

    topcup.pos = eie


    a.z = a.z + 1

    b.z = b.z + 1

    c.z = c.z + 1

    d.z = d.z +1

    e.z = e.z + 1

    f.z = f.z + 1

    g.z = g.z + 1

    h.z = h.z + 1

    i.z = i.z + 1

    j.z = j.z + 1

    k.z = k.z + 1

    l.z = l.z + 1

    m.z = m.z + 1

    n.z = n.z + 1

    o.z = o.z + 1

    p.z = p.z + 1

    q.z = q.z + 1

    r.z = r.z + 1

    s.z = s.z + 1

    t.z = t.z + 1

    u.z = u.z + 1

    v.z = v.z + 1

    w.z = w.z + 1

    x.z = x.z + 1

    y.z = y.z + 1

    z.z = z.z + 1

    aia.z = aia.z + 1

    bib.z = bib.z + 1

    cic.z = cic.z + 1

    did.z = did.z + 1

    eie.z = eie.z + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

I got it, there's an auto zoom thing in VPython called autoscaling and in order to turn that off, the code is  `scene.autoscale = False` and all you do is place it before the while loop. And it stops the camera from zooming out in order to keep all the objects in the frame.